# Scroll to top code not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have the code here but for some reason it will not work on my site. I've tried most everything but it still wont work. Any help would be much welcomed. Thanks.

http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/J3zyq/3/

```
<a id="goTop">Top</a>
```

\

```
#goTop{
background:red;
padding:5px;
position:fixed;
top:-100px;
right:10px;
}
```

/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() > 100){
        $('#goTop').stop().animate({
            top: '20px'    
            }, 500);
    }
    else{
        $('#goTop').stop().animate({
           top: '-100px'    
        }, 500);
    }
});
$('#goTop').click(function() {
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
       scrollTop: 0
    }, 500, function() {
       $('#goTop').stop().animate({
           top: '-100px'    
       }, 500);
    });
});
});
```

Comment: what is not working?

Comment: it's actually working from your fiddle

Comment: I just tested your fiddle in chrome and IE11 and it's working. Any chance you can get the whole cord of your site on the fiddle

Comment: @brigysl Well using the code below it works, only it seems to be to high up? (I have a header image it's behind?" I think it needs to drop down twice as much.

Comment: @CharieBurns then change `top: '20px'` to `top: '40px'`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(this).scrollTop() > 100){
            $('#goTop').animate({
                top: '20px'    
                }, 100);
        }
        else{
            $('#goTop').animate({
               top: '-100px'    
            }, 100);
        }
    });
    $('#goTop').click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
           scrollTop: 0
        }, 500 );
    });
});
```

Comment: Well using this code it works, only it seems to be to high up? (I have a header image it's behind?" I think it needs to drop down twice as much